# How to pass parameter to Controller method referenced in Laravel Routes?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I am trying to use a method to implement accept/reject since I will be updating the same model with just little difference.

How can I pass a parameter to a controller method directly from Laravel Routes (i.e. instead of being supplied via url).

E.g. something like:

```
Route::put('/friends/{friend}/reject', ['as' => 'friends.reject', 'uses' =>  'FriendsController@accept', 'accept' => false]);
Route::put('/friends/{friend}/accept', ['as' => 'friends.reject', 'uses' =>  'FriendsController@accept']);
```

My controller code looks like:

```
public function accept($friend, $accept = true)
{
    ...
```

Is it possible to define the `$accept` parameter inside the Routes config file?

Answer (score 2):

I have an improvement over the answer you found yourself. By adding a [route constraint](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-parameters) you make sure that only the two `verb`s are allowed.
Also I changed the naming to make more sense. If it doesn't, just change it ;)

```
Route::put('/friends/{friend}/{verb}',
    ['as' => 'friends.respond-to-request',
    'uses' =>  'FriendsController@respondToRequest']
)->where('verb', '(accept|reject)');
```

Comment: This is really a nice tip.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution:

```
Route::put('/friends/{friend}/reject',array('as' => 'friends.reject',function($friend){
    $accept = false;
    $app = app();
    $controller = $app->make('FriendsController');
    $controller->callAction($app, $app['router'], 'accept', $parameters = array($friend, $accept));
}));
```

This code uses a Closure. In this closure the controller will be dispatched by laravel's router.

Answer (score 0):

I finally resorted to:

```
Route::put('/friends/{friend}/{verb}', ['as' => 'friends.reject', 'uses' =>  'FriendsController@accept']);

public function accept($friend, $verb = 'accept')
{
    ...//check if `verb` is 'accept' or 'reject' here..
```

I am not sure this is an ideal solution though, maybe it's better to implement with integer but it's possible Laravel processes both the same way.